# Javascript (d3.js) - different console log output on consecutive statements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can't seem to get to the bottom of this issue. I have the following Javascript code:

```
for(var i=0; i<links1.length; ++i) {
  console.log(links1[i]);
}
console.log(links1);
```

And the output from the for loop is as follows:

```
Object {source: 2, target: 16} 
Object {source: 32, target: 15} 
Object {source: 32, target: 31} 
Object {source: 16, target: 104} 
Object {source: 104, target: 32} 
...
```

While the console.log(links1) line produces:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
source: Object
target: Object
__proto__: Object
1: Object
source: undefined
target: Object
__proto__: Object
2: Object
source: 32
target: 31
__proto__: Object
3: Object
source: 16
target: 104
__proto__: Object
4: Object
source: 104
target: 32
__proto__: Object
...
```

Why in the world am I getting different values for the first two elements?

There are no AJAX calls going on in the background and the d3.js methods being called are parseRows (which should not be async).

If relevant, the context of the code is:

```
function draw_graph(nodes1, links1) {
    var width = 500;
    var height = 500;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-120)
        .linkDistance(30)
        .size([width, height]);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    console.log('tu');
    for(var i=0; i<links1.length; ++i) {
        console.log(links1[i]);
    }
    console.log(links1);
    console.log(nodes1);

    force
        .nodes(nodes1)
        .links(links1)
        .start();

    ...
}

d3.text("test1.txt", function(text) {
    var nodes = [];

    rows = d3.dsv(" ", "text/plain").parseRows(text);

    for(var i=0; i<rows.length; ++i) {
        newEl = {name:+rows[i][0], value:+rows[i][0]};
        nodes.push(newEl);
    }

    d3.text("test2.txt", function(text) {
        var links = [];

        rows = d3.dsv(" ", "text/plain").parseRows(text);

        for(var i=0; i<rows.length; ++i) {
            newEl = {source:+(rows[i][0]), target:+(rows[i][1])};
            links.push(newEl);
        }

        draw_graph(nodes, links);

    });


});
```

...which dies at

```
force
    .nodes(nodes1)
    .links(links1)
    .start();
```

with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined d3.js:6244
force.start d3.js:6244
draw_graph test.php:58
(anonymous function) test.php:113
(anonymous function) d3.js:1931
(anonymous function) d3.js:1916
event d3.js:434
respond
```

If anyone has an idea about what I am doing wrong please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: What browser do you use? If you use Chrome and you expand the output of `console.log(links1)` in the console to view its content you will see the current state of the object and not the state of the object at the time when `console.log(links1)` was called. Thats why it could be different to `console.log(links1[i]);`. This will indicate that some code that is executed after your loop is modifying  `links1`.

Comment: Ahhh, well that cleared up some things. Thank you kind sir!